# Postfix: Forward/Reroute mails with unknown recipients

Tags: postfix, email

I'm running a postfix/dovecot mail server and everything works quite well.
What I want to do now is forward all mails with a recipient that does not have an entry in the local recipient table, to another, existing user.

I've tried google'ing around, but I haven't found anything...it seems like this is an uncommon thing to do.

Does anyone know how to do that, or can maybe point me to a lead?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, using simple aliases works well enough for me.
In case someone else needs a hint on this, I used this link to set up mail redirection:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-redirect-one-users-mail-to-another-user-with-postfix.html